# Error using HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

After I added some lines of code, I can't start my aplication on glassfish server. I don't know what its wrong. it's my first time working with **HttpServletRequest**  & **HttpServletResponse**

Here is the code I have written so far :

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import rptws.RptwsWebService;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 *
 * Llamado a servicios del RptGen.
 * 
 * 
 */

@WebService()
public class WSDigitalizacion extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WSDigitalizacion.class.getName());
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/sundadesa.hospitalitaliano.net_38084/rptws/RptwsWebService.wsdl")
    private RptwsWebService service;     

/**
 * 
 * @param cAccion
 * @param iArea
 * @param iUsr
 * @param cParametrosXml
 * @param request 
 * @param response
 * 
 * @return Resultado de la llamada al RptWs.
 * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "callRptWS")
public String callRptWS(@WebParam(name = "cAccion") String cAccion, 
                        @WebParam(name = "iArea") long iArea, 
                        @WebParam(name = "iUsr") long iUsr, 
                        @WebParam(name = "cParametrosXml") String cParametrosXml,
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {  
    
        String result;
    try { // Call Web Service Operation
        String url_wsdl = utils.Utils.getUrlWsdlRptWs();
        service = new rptws.RptwsWebService(new URL(url_wsdl), new QName("http://rptws/", "RptwsWebService"));
        rptws.RptwsWeb port = service.getRptwsWebPort();
        result = port.rptGenWS(cAccion, iArea, iUsr, cParametrosXml);
        //System.out.println("Result = "+result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
    
}}
```

The code before the edition was

```
package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import rptws.RptwsWebService;



/**
 *
 * Llamado a servicios del RptGen.
 * 
 * 
 */
@WebService()
public class WSDigitalizacion {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WSDigitalizacion.class.getName());
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/sundadesa.hospitalitaliano.net_38084/rptws/RptwsWebService.wsdl")
    private RptwsWebService service;     
    
/**
 * 
 * @param cAccion
 * @param iArea
 * @param iUsr
 * @param cParametrosXml
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * @return Resultado de la llamada al RptWs.
 * 
 * 
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "callRptWS")
public String callRptWS(@WebParam(name = "cAccion") String cAccion, 
                        @WebParam(name = "iArea") long iArea, 
                        @WebParam(name = "iUsr") long iUsr, 
                        @WebParam(name = "cParametrosXml") String cParametrosXml)   {  
    
        String result;
    try { // Call Web Service Operation
        String url_wsdl = utils.Utils.getUrlWsdlRptWs();
        service = new rptws.RptwsWebService(new URL(url_wsdl), new QName("http://rptws/", "RptwsWebService"));
        rptws.RptwsWeb port = service.getRptwsWebPort();
        result = port.rptGenWS(cAccion, iArea, iUsr, cParametrosXml);
        //System.out.println("Result = "+result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
    
}
```

}

I don't know how to use HttpServletRequest & HttpServletResponse, my intetion was to securize the function `callRptWS()` because at this moment it's returning data without any security parameter

I'm using JDK 1.8

Comment: "I can't execute my application" is not a problem description. NB There is no [tag:jsp] here.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the error. You can't use HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse because it's a soap method, you need to use instead Interface [WebServiceContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html)